# Simple CLI to append one file to the end of another

Tags: command-line, bash

If I have two text files, file1.txt.and file2.txt, how do I append the contents of file2.txt to file1.txt (without overwriting file1.txt) using a simple command-line?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, the simplest way would be:

```
cat file2.txt >> file1.txt
```

Reference: [Appending Redirected Output](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output).

Answer (score 3):

Bash redirection would be my first choice but if you're dealing with squiffy permissions (eg the file is root-owned), I would use `tee`. Here's an example where we're pretending `file1.txt` is owned by root (or at least, isn't writable by `$USER`):

```
cat file2.txt | sudo tee -a file1.txt
```